# counter method does not count well

Tags: python, odoo

I have a method that tells the times that a worker makes a sale, but it does not work because it only marks me that he has made 1 but has actually done 5. Next I leave an image and the code used to guide me.

```
**class Worker (models.Model):**

    _name = 'project_rc.worker'

    sales_counter = fields.Integer (string = "Sales made", compute = "get_sales_made")
    document_ids = fields.One2many (comodel_name = 'project_rc.document', 
    inverse_name = 'worker_id', string = 'Invoice')

def get_sales_made (self):

      count = self.env ['project_rc.type_movement']. search_count ([('type_movement', '=', 'sale')])

      self.counter_sale = count


**class Document (models.Model):**

    type_movement_id = fields.Many2one (comodel_name = 'project_rc.type_movement', string = "Movement type")

    worker_id = fields.Many2one (asdel_name = 'project_rc.worker', string = "Worker")

**class Type_Movement (models.Model):**

    type_movement = fields.Selection ([('purchase', 'Purchase'), ('sale', 'Sale'), ('merma', 'Merma')], string = "Movement type")

    document_ids = fields.One2many (comodel_name = 'project_rc.document', inverse_name = 'type_movimiento_id', string = 'Document')
```

Sample picture: https://ibb.co/vs0dw5K

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Please repair your posted code so that it runs.  Include your current and desired output in the question; off-site links and images are not acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching in the wrong table it should be `project_rc.document`

```
self.env['project_rc.document'].search_count([('type_movement_id.type_movement', '=', 'sale')
                                              ('worker_id', '=', rec.id)
                                             ])
```

Or you can simply [filter](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model.filtered) `document_ids` to count sales.

Answer (score 1):

The problem came from your function get_sales_made

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    _name = 'project_rc.worker'
    sales_counter = fields.Integer(string="Sales made", compute="get_sales_made")
    document_ids = fields.One2many('project_rc.document', 'worker_id', string='Invoice')

    @api.depends('document_ids')
    def get_sales_made(self):
        for rec in self:
            document = rec.document_ids.filtered(lambda r: r.type_movement_id and r.type_movement_id.type_movement == 'sale')
            rec.sales_counter = len(document)


class Document(models.Model):
    _name = 'project_rc.document'

    type_movement_id = fields.Many2one('project_rc.type_movement', string="Movement type")
    worker_id = fields.Many2one('project_rc.worker', string="Worker")


class Type_Movement(models.Model):
    _name = 'project_rc.type_movement'

    type_movement = fields.Selection([('purchase', 'Purchase'), ('sale', 'Sale'), ('merma', 'Merma')], string="Movement type")
    document_ids = fields.One2many('project_rc.document', 'type_movement_id', string='Document')
```